# Spark Streaming not reading input coming from the other ip

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am in spark Streaming context, and i am reading input from the the socket using nc -lk 9999. When i am running it and manually giving input it's working.
But, if input is coming from different ip to this socket then spark is not reading that input, though it's showing all the input coming from different source under nc -lk 9999. But somehow spark is not reading it, while if i copy and paste same data, it works.

I am not sure what can be issue. Does anyone has idea about it? Thanks in advance.

For reference, my program:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HBaseStream")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    // create a StreamingContext, the main entry point for all streaming functionality
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))
    val inputStream = ssc.socketTextStream(<hostname>, 9999)
    .......
}
```

Data coming form different host to this socket:
[root@ ~]# nc -lk 9999
56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1f01,id1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
56b4b2b23c24c3608376d1f0,id2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

Comment: Are you able to telnet on another host e.g. `telnet <hostname> 9999` to cross check any firewall issue?

Comment: Ya, it's able to connect : <other_machine>:/tmp$ telnet <hostname> 9999
Trying 192.168.186.97...
Connected to <hostname>.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: One more check.. suppose on host1 you have started `nc -lk 9999` then from host2 (where you are running hour spark program) are you able to receive message through `nc <host> 9999` command ?

Comment: Hi Mahendra thanks, yes i am able to receive data from remote host to my local, where i am running spark-streaming program.

Comment: Do you end the stream with a line terminator? socketTextStream will read till found line terminator.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, yeah stream was with line terminator. I found that when i changed the host, i added in the spark-streaming to the remote host. It starts working. But, i am still not sure how to deal with multiple remote hosts. So i am exploring Kafka for this.